# A function that returns an array which is the intersection of two other arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, intersection

```
function arraysCommon(array1, array2) {
  return array1.filter(x => array2.includes(x));
}
```

This function does not work the way I want it to.
For instance given `array1 = [1,2,3,2,1]` and `array2 = [5,4,3,2,1]`
it returns `[1,2,3,2,1]`, since the elements `1,2,3` are seen in both arrays.
But I want it to return `[1,2,3]` in that order since `1,2,3` are seen only once in `array2` and are treated as seperate entities.

So pretty much the functionality should be that

- Each element in the first array can map to at most one element in the second array.
- Duplicated elements in each array are treated as separate entities.
- the first array determines the order

I have attempted to loop through the arrays and check and compare the number of duplicates in each array but I can't seem to get the logic working correctly. Is there a different way to approach this?

I've attached an image of two Venn diagrams that might clarify the difference
[image: I've attached an image of two Venn diagrams that might clarify the difference]

Comment: What is your expected output for `array1 = [1,2,3,2,1]` and `array2 = [5,4,3,2,1,2]`? Is it still `[1,2,3]` or would it be `[1,2,3,2]`

Comment: the expected output is [1,2,3]

Comment: For the input @NickParsons suggested it should be [1,2,2,3] right? Two seperate 2s exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it gets more complicated because you need to know what numbers you have already added. In this case you need a temporary array to hold the result. We also need to track if a number exists in the array two times.

Try this:

```js
function arraysCommon(array1, array2) {
  //Copy array2 by duplicating and spreading the elements into another array.
  var copyArray2 = [...array2];
  //Temperary Array
  var temp = [];
  for (let x of array1) {
      //Check if the element is in the first array and not already added to the temp array
      if (copyArray2.includes(x)) {
          temp.push(x);
          //Remove item from copy array2 so it cannot be used anymore
          copyArray2.splice(copyArray2.indexOf(x), 1);
      }
  } 
  //Return the temp array
  return temp;
}

console.log(arraysCommon([1,2,3,2,1], [5,4,3,2,1]))
console.log(arraysCommon([1,2,3,2,1], [2,2,3,3,4]))
```

Comment: What if the function was given array1 = [1,2,3,2,1] and array2 = [2,2,3,3,4]. It is supposed to return [2,3,2] since there are two 2s in both the arrays but only one 3 in array1. The function you gave returns only [2,3]

Comment: Then it returns [2, 3].  The common numbers of both arrays. Did I miss something?

Comment: yes it is supposed to return another 2 as well output: [2,3,2], since the 2s are treated as seperate entities.

Comment: @Kifaya Shehadeh Thank you, I totally missed that point. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

this should work as you wanted!

```
// test 1 
const array1 = [1,4,1,1,5,9,2,7];
const array2 = [1,8,2,5,1];

// test 2
const array3 = [1,2,3,2,1];
const array4 = [5,4,3,2,1];

const mapper = (array1, array2) => {
  var obj = {};
  array1.forEach((x, indexX) => {
    array2.forEach((y, indexY) => {
      if (x == y) {
        if (!Object.values(obj).includes(indexX) && !obj.hasOwnProperty(indexY)) {
          obj[indexY] = indexX;
          return;
        }
      }
    }) 
  })
  return Object.values(obj).sort().map(values => array1[values]);
}

console.log(mapper(array1, array2));
console.log(mapper(array3, array4));
```

I hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

With sorting and counting this should be possible. Since you are incrementing when you find similar characters, this should be okay:

```js
const array1= [1,4,1,1,5,9,2,7];
const array2 = [1,8,2,5,1]

const array3 = [1,2,3,2,1];
const array4 = [5,4,3,2,1,2]

const array5 = [1,2,3,2,1];
const array6 = [2,2,3,3,4]
function arraysCommon(array1, array2) {
  const ans = [];
  array1.sort();
  array2.sort();
  let j = 0;
  let i = 0;
  while(i<array1.length && j<array2.length){
    if(array1[i] === array2[j]){
      ans.push(array1[i]);
      i++;
      j++;
    }
    else if(array2[i] > array1[j]){
    i++;
    }
    else{
    j++;
    }
  }
  console.log(ans);
}

arraysCommon(array1,array2);
arraysCommon(array3,array4);
arraysCommon(array5,array6);
```

Comment: _the first array determines the order_ - is this requirement satisfied by your approach? This cannot be satisfied when you sort the input arrays

Answer (score -1):

You can instance a new Set, wich brings only unique values and than retorn a array from this set.

Something like this:

```
function arraysCommon(array1, array2) {
  const filtered = array1.filter(x => array2.includes(x));
  const uniqueValues = new Set(filtered)
  return Array.from(uniqueValues)
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for `array1 = [1,2,3,2,1]` and `array2 = [5,4,3,2,1,2]`. The question specifies: "Duplicated elements in each array are treated as separate entities."

Comment: I not sure about which part dont will work, the expected return is `[1,2,3]` and is exactly what the function return given this 2 arrays.

Comment: What if the parameters were array1= [1,4,1,1,5,9,2,7] and array2 = [1,8,2,5,1], Then it should return [1,1,5,2] since there are two 1s common to both arrays because they are treated as seperate entities. Your function returns [1,5,2]  :(( @IncognitaDev